# Pandas count if number of occurrence greater than x in rolling 7 day interval

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data with `time_stamp` and `user_id`.

The data is sorted on `user_id` and `time_stamp`.

I want to get for each `user_id`, in a 7 day rolling interval, count number of visits in that 7 day rolling interval. If the number of visits > 3 then set a new column for that user_id as 1 else 0.

**my data**

```
time_stamp,user_id,visited
2014-04-22 03:53:30,1,1
2013-11-15 03:45:04,2,1
2013-11-29 03:45:04,2,1
2013-12-09 03:45:04,2,1
2013-12-25 03:45:04,2,1
2013-12-31 03:45:04,2,1
2014-01-08 03:45:04,2,1
2014-02-03 03:45:04,2,1 <- in a 7 day interval (till 2014-02-10)
2014-02-08 03:45:04,2,1 <- there is 3 visits
2014-02-09 03:45:04,2,1 <-
```

**expected output**

```
user_id outcome
1       0
2       1
```

**what i tried:**

I don't know best way to do this. My first idea is to get consecutive time difference for each `user_id`.

```
df['timediff'] = df.groupby(['user_id','time_stamp'])['time_stamp'].diff() / np.timedelta64(1, 'D')
```

**But this output gave all Nans.**

```
    2014-04-22 03:53:30 1   1   NaN
1   2013-11-15 03:45:04 2   1   NaN
2   2013-11-29 03:45:04 2   1   NaN
3   2013-12-09 03:45:04 2   1   NaN
4   2013-12-25 03:45:04 2   1   NaN
```

How should I change the algorithm please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use [`df.rolling`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html) with an offset of 7 days if you have a series for every user_id. Then you can check if anywhere in the series, the rolling sum is [greater than or equal to](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable//reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ge.html) 3. To get the series per user, use [`set_index()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) and [`unstack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html):

```
(df.set_index(['time_stamp', 'user_id'])
.unstack()
.rolling('7D')
.sum()
.ge(3)
.any())

#         user_id
#visited  1          False
#         2           True
```